# Release date for Apache Spark 3.3

Tags: apache-spark

Does anyone know the release date for Apache Spark 3.3 ? We have log4j vulnerability reported in Apache Spark 3.2.1 version and want to see if the next patch is going to fix it or not.

Regards,
VM

Comment: try excluding log4j from spark-core dependency and add the compatible log4j version (with security fix) as a separate dependency

Answer (score 2):

3.3 seems to have gone through some delays but should enter the RC process soon.

Release cadence details are (as of this answer) listed on the Versioning Policy page at https://spark.apache.org/versioning-policy.html

Currently you'll see the following at the bottom:

#### Spark 3.3 release window

| Date | Event |
| --- | --- |
| March 15th 2022 | Code freeze. Release branch cut. |
| Late March 2022 | QA period. Focus on bug fixes, tests, stability and docs. Generally, no new features merged. |
| April 2022 | Release candidates (RC), voting, etc. until final release passes |

So you now know as much as I do. If you want to know more you can follow the mailing list: https://lists.apache.org/list.html?dev@spark.apache.org

If you're by chance using Spark on Databricks, though, they typically release feature updates in the runtime releases before they go to RC in the OSS version.

You mentioned a vulnerability in log4j... CVE-2021-44832 should not exist in the current release Spark 3.2.1. Can you provide more details on what you're seeing in your vulnerability report?

Comment: Looks like Maxim Gekk has reported on the 3.3 RC thread that he'll be cutting the first RC next week

Comment: There have been some delays but they're well on their way to finalizing the first RC.

@user18730346 if this satisfies your question please mark this as the accepted answer.